# Utilising methods available in plugin1 in plugin2 via MEF

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have a console based MEF application the host (`CompositionContainer`) of which loads available plugin assemblies based on the command line parameter, for example:

```
app.exe plugin1
```

will load the host (app.exe) and plugin1. The VS solution is structured such that each plugin has it's own project (hence it's own assembly).

There exists a collection of plugins, some of which have opportunity for re-use of code. So for example `plugin1` has a method `CopyFiles(string fileName)` and that same functionality is to be utilised by `plugin2`.

Now, in a traditional console application one would add a reference to `plugin1.dll` and by using that namespace go about it's business of re-use.

I am curious if there is a "MEF" way, if you will, of implementing this re-use. So, something along the lines of creating an object of `plugin1` in `plugin2` by adding an `Import` attribute to `plugin1's` exportable interface and letting MEF take care of the rest. Is that possible? And if so, how?

Or is there a better approach that one should take when designing such applications? Bonus voodoo for any pointers to useful learning resources and explanations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method you want to share is in `plugin1`, you would `Export` `plugin1`.  You can also `Export` a method if you just wanted to share that method.

`plugin2` would `Import` plugin1.  MEF would take care of the rest.  If you are getting your assemblies from the command line and creating an `AssemblyCatalog` for `plugin1`, then you will also need to tell it about `plugin2` and get that into an `AggregateCatalog`, or put them all in a directory and use a `DirectoryCatalog` (you could pass the directory name on the command line).

The [MEF Programming Guide](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guide&referringTitle=Documentation) covers similar scenarios.

There are also Hands-On-Labs for MEF in the [Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4 Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23507) which are helpful.